# Proper json to back end post call

Tags: java, json, angularjs, http, post

I'm having some troubles with different back-end processing of POST rest calls. I have two different objects which are updated through two different POST methods in my back-end. I catch the objects as a JsonNode, and in order to parse the attributes which I need to update, i create an iterator like so :

```
final Iterator<String> fieldNames = attributes.fieldNames();
```

The problem comes when I send my data from angular, in one case I need to explicitly send it like angular.toJson(data) in order to properly grab all the field names, and in the other case I just send the data (without the angular json conversion). Why is this behavior occurring ? Does this have to do with how I create the $http post call ? Here are the two different calls from angular:

```
$http.post(URL, angular.toJson(data)).success(function(data){
 /*whatever*/ }).error(function(data) {
 /*whatever*/ });

//Second call looks like this
var promise = $http({method: 'POST', url:URL, data:data, cache:'false'});
//this one i resolve using $q.all
```

I truncated the code to just the important stuff. My data is created like this currently(tried multiple ways in order to skip the need for toJson):

```
var data = "{\"Attribute1:\"+"\""+$scope.value1+"\","+
             "\"Attribute2:\"+"\""+$scope.value2+"\"}";
```

How do I need to send the json data in order for it to correctly be converted to a JsonNode in my back-end, so I can properly iterate the fieldNames ?

Comment: Do the cases depend on what the data var looks like? Eg. sometimes data is a string, and other times it is a js dictionary?

Comment: From what I've seen, the behavior is the same even if it's a js dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to come to a common solution which consumes the json correctly in my back-end. I declared my json objects in angular like this :

```
$scope.dataToSend = {
    "SomeAttribute" : "",
    "SomeOtherAttribute" : ""
};
```

And then added my values like so :

```
$scope.dataTosend.SomeAttribute = someValue;
$scope.dataTosend.SomeOtherAttribute = someOtherValue;
```

No longer need to send the data with angular.toJson().